# online examination how to store radio button value when multiple questions are displayed in php

Tags: php

```
  <?php
     include "connect.php";
     session_start();
     $servedQuestions = array(0);
     $c="SELECT * from `qa`;";
     $r=mysqli_query($conn,$c);
     $count=mysqli_num_rows($r);
     while(count($servedQuestions) <= 5) {
        $n1 = mt_rand(1,$count);
        if (in_array($n1, $servedQuestions))
          continue;
        $servedQuestions[] = $n1;
     }
     $selected=[];
     for($i=1;$i<count($servedQuestions);$i++){
       echo "<br>";
       $get_question="SELECT * from `qa` WHERE qno = 
                        `'".$servedQuestions[$i]."';"; 
       $result=mysqli_query($conn,$get_question);
       $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       $qno=$row['qno'];
       $question=$row['question'];
       $opt1=$row['opt1'];
       $opt2=$row['opt2'];
       $opt3=$row['opt3'];
       $opt4=$row['opt4'];
       echo "QUESTION: $i <br>&nbsp<br>";   
       echo"$question <br><br> "; 
       echo"<input type='radio'name='response[$qno]'value='1'>$opt1<br> "; 
       echo"<input type='radio' name='response[$qno]' value='2'>$opt2<br> ";
       echo"<input type='radio' name='response[$qno]' value='3'>$opt3 <br>";
       echo"<input type='radio' name='response[$qno]' value='4'>$opt4<br>"; 
       echo "<br>";
       $v=$_POST['response['.$qno.']'];
       echo $v;
   ?>
```

initally code generate 5 random numbers for those numbers 5 random questions are displayed . when Im trying to echo the value of radio button its say that undefined index .im not able to print the value of radio button.

Comment: By radio button value, you mean answers selected for a question right?

Comment: Can you edit the question a bit? It's hard to work out what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of naming your radio buttons like:

```
<input type='radio'name='response[$qno]'value='1'>$opt1<br>
```

You can name it like this:

```
<input type='radio'name='$qno_response'value='1'>$opt1<br>
```

On your backend side (`php`), you can access the radio buttons as:

```
for($i=1;$i<count($servedQuestions);$i++)//Or you can have your own way of getting the list of questions generated
{
  $QuestionAnswer = $_POST[$qno.'_response'];
 //This will work like:
 //$QuestionAnswer = $_POST['1_response']; //for first question
 //$QuestionAnswer = $_POST['2_response']; //for second question and so on..
}
```

Comment: yes i did the same thing but im getting a notice  Undefined index: 1_response. im unable to understand why im getting . I have a doubt i did not write form tag now can i use $_POST[]???

Comment: If you want to implement without form tag then you need to go with AJAX.